Flux unit conversion
I have a jwst nircam image of a galactic field. The science images are in units of MegaJansky per steradian (MJy/sr), and so the zeropoint is 28.08652 AB mag . When I ran sextractor on this image , I got my flux in units of counts(as per the output of Sextractor catalogue)
#   6 FLUX_APER              Flux vector within fixed circular aperture(s)              [count]

I wanted to convert my flux into units of uJy which could be used with eazy for redshift determination.How can I convert the sextractor output flux into units of uJy

The answer is in the NIRcam docs, but I’ll quote the relevant bit here:

To measure photometry in MJy, convert the image to units of MJy/pixel by multiplying by the average area of a pixel in sr, a constant provided in the FITS header keyword PIXAR_SR. Note this value varies slightly (by a few percent) among the 8 short wavelength detectors and between the 2 long wavelength detectors. They correspond approximately to the nominal pixel sizes: 0.031" and 0.063", for the short and long wavelength channels, respectively.

So find that PIXAR_SR value in the image header, and you’ll have your conversion to MJy; then just convert MJy -> uJy if desired.

It's maybe worth pointing out that it's maybe easiest to do this to the image before running SExtractor. Then the "counts" values reported by SExtractor will be MJy.

@PeterErwin could you please explain this a bit further, so that I could catch up.

@Alan In case it isn't clear, SExtractor treats pixel values as "counts" (it doesn't know about different flux units). If the pixel values are actually MJr/sr, then that's what "counts" means.  But MJy/sr is a surface brightness unit; you have to divide by the pixel area, as Eric Jensen notes. My suggestion was that you do this to the image before running SExtractor; then the SE "counts" are precisely MJy.

@PeterErwin Thanks for the commands.
